# How to free memory for vector of vectors (C++)

Tags: c++, vector, swap

I have a `vector<vector<double>> elem` and I want to deallocate its memory many times in my program.

I tried using

```
vector<vector<double>>().swap(elem);
```

Or even a for cicle

```
for(int i=0; i<elem.size();i++)
    vector<double>().swap(elem[i]);
vector<vector<double>>().swap(elem);
elem.resize(dim, vector<double>(0));
```

(I want the first dimension to be a certain number `dim`)

But when I call

```
cout<<elem[0].size();
```

numerous times in my program, the output keeps growing, even if I've just used the aforementioned method. This issue isn't present with the "main" size of the vector.

i.e.

```
cout<<elem.size();
```

always outputs `dim`

EDIT: I know about clear() but I want to deallocate the vector, shrink_to_fit() doesn't work either. Also this is implemented in a function out of the main one, as follows:

```
void arrayReset(vector<vector<double>> elem) {
        for(int i=0; i<elem.size();i++)
        vector<double>().swap(elem[i]);
    vector<vector<double>>().swap(elem);
    elem.resize(dim, vector<double>(0));
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to clear or replace these vectors? Normally you don't need to free or deallocate if you manipulate them correctly. It's all done automatically. Maybe you just want [`clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear)?

Comment: *I want to deallocate its memory many times* That is very inefficient.  You should allocate once, and then just reuse the storage as needed.  vector has a `clear` member function that will help you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new function `void arrayReset(vector<vector<double>> elem) {` gets a *COPY* of your vector and [possibly] cleans it; you never see it in the calling function.

If you pass your vector by reference, you would manipulate the original vector.

Comment: Another example of why people are asked to post complete, minimal programs that reproduce the error... :-(

Answer (score 1):

> How to free memory for vector

The way is the same for all vectors regardless of the element type.

Step 1: Remove the elements of the vector. Simplest way is the `clear` member function. After this step, the `size` member function will return 0.

Step 2: Call `shrink_to_fit` member function which requests the memory to be deallocated. After this step, `capacity` may return 0.

Technically, `shrink_to_fit` is a request that is not required to be honoured by the language implementation. The only guaranteed way to deallocate the memory is to destroy the vector. Example:

```
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double> vector;
    // use vector here
}
// memory has been deallocated
```

> I want to deallocate its memory many times in my program.

Note that this is typically slower than not deallocating many times. I recommend making sure that you want something that is actually useful.

Comment: I also tried the clear()/shrink_to_fit() way, but it seems like I can't clear that vector. The vector is emptied in a separate void function out of the main one.

Comment: @userakai `clear` will remove all elements from the vector.